# Applescript | Javascript - Click on Link using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, applescript

I am trying to get applescript to click on the (link), I have posted the code below, i have tried many ways but i am unable to get it work. Also the link is different every time so i cant just copy that link into it. Thanks in advanced! Also This is all the code to do with it (I think) i want it to click on the date of last upload: (Link)

```
<div class="span4 offset1">
                            <ul class="unstyled">
                                <li>Monthly Views: <strong class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="data-na" data-original-title="" title="">NA</a></strong></li>
                                <li>Daily New Views: <strong class="pull-right">18,830</strong></li>
                                <li>Daily New Subscribers: <strong class="pull-right">33</strong></li>
                                <li>Total Views: <strong class="pull-right">298,481</strong></li>
                                <li>Total Channel Views: <strong class="pull-right">3,467</strong></li>
                                <li>Total Subscribers: <strong class="pull-right">649</strong></li>
                                <li id="date-of-last-upload">Date of Last Upload: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVrV-OmDJcw&amp;feature=youtube_gdata" target="_BLANK">(link)</a><strong class="pull-right">14-01-10 @ 08:18:36 pm</strong></li>
                                <li class="clearfix">Partner:
                                    <strong class="pull-right">
                                                                                                                                                                TheDeeman25+user                                                                                                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for but you can get the value of the href attribute of the anchor tag by getting `childNodes`. The value returned by JavaScript is the URL you want to set your document eventually. Instead of using a click I get the desired location and set the URL of document 1 to it; the result/goal will be the same as a click.

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1
        set URL of it to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('date-of-last-upload').childNodes[1].href"
    end tell
end tell
```

EDIT: to open the url in a new tab (if opening links in tab is set to automatic in preferences) you can change the `set URL of it to` into `open location`

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1
        open location (do JavaScript "document.getElementById('date-of-last-upload').childNodes[1].href")
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Also, How would i make it open in a new tab? (im a noob to javascript)

Comment: Cheers, your the best!

Comment: Hey, How would i do the same thing for the first channel on this websight? http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/Iebattlegrounds/similarrank/sbscore

Comment: Like the similar channels table

Comment: I would suggest to take our conversation further in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50291/applescript .